# Как обновлять html в цикле for?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть пример такого кода, я что то не пойму почему он не обновляется при каждой итерации в цикле.

То есть должно работать быть как подобие секундомера, а он вместо этого заменяет только в самом конце цикла.

**Задержка в цикле не нужна, цикл должен работать быстро!**

```js
for(var i = 0; i <= 200000; i++){
  $('#data').html(i);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data">0</div>
```

Объясните пожалуйста в чем причина?

Comment: В браузере есть event-loop.
Ваш цикл работает в рамках обработки какого-то события.
Пока обработка события не закончена, ничего дальше обрабатываться и перерисовываться не будет.

Comment: Задержка нужна для того, чтобы ты увидел, число на каждой итерации. Сейчас как раз без задержки и работает. :)